# Drupal 7 commerce stripe stripe-php library refuse to load

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm trying to implement commerce on my D7 site and after installing packs of modules I've installed commerce_stripe module to use Stripe payments.

After I created all necessary things(stripe account, products, stripe api keys, latest stripe-php library in sites/all/libraries/) I'm trying to proceed payment and see an error:

Error making the payment. Please contact shop admin to proceed.

Went to reports -> recent log messages and see:

Failure to load Stripe API PHP Client Library.

Hours of googling and I found few ways how to handle it. Updated Libraries module to the latest version, instead of 7.x-3.0-alpha installed 7.x-3.x-dev, clear cache, run cron.
Unfortunately, nothing happens.

trying to locate an error I've found function that trying to load stripe php library. It's `commerce_stripe_load_library()` in commerce_stripe.module file. Error throws in the beginning of this function:

```
$library = libraries_load('stripe-php');
  if (!$library || empty($library['loaded'])) {
    watchdog('commerce_stripe', 'Failure to load Stripe API PHP Client Library.', array(), WATCHDOG_CRITICAL);
    return FALSE;
  }
```

Trying to dpm result of `libraries_load()` function.
and first condition `!$library` is passed successfully.
But `$library['loaded']` is `FALSE`.

Any ideas why? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report or support request to a third-party project hosted on drupal.org or elsewhere and must be reported in it's issue queue there to track issues in a single place, not here.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution.

There is wrong information about installing library on drupal dot org.

It says

> ### Installation
>
> Install and activate Commerce Stripe and Libraries modules.
>
> Download the latest Stripe PHP release from GitHub.
>
> Extract the contents of the archive into the directory /sites/all/libraries/stripe-php
>
> Create an account at Stripe.com, and insert your API keys from the Stripe
>
> Dashboard into the Commerce Stripe payment method settings at admin/commerce/config/payment-methods.

So the thing is that this is the wrong information. If you go to `commerce_stripe.module` and find hook `commerce_stripe_libraries_info()` in `'version arguments'` you will see that it tries to locate in file VERSION this pattern:

`'pattern' => '/(3.\d+(\.\d+)?)/',`

It means that you need version 3 of stripe-php library(depends on your commerce_stripe module version).
So fix for this is to use correct version of stripe-php library

## UPDATE

You can check necessary library's status by executing `drush library-list`

you will see something like this:

```
Name                   Status        Version  Variants          Dependencies  Provider        
stripe-php             Not detected           -                 -             Commerce Stripe
```

if stripe-php library's status is not detected, then you user wrong version or place the library to the wrong place.

Comment: If the documentation on drupal.org is wrong, please open a "bug report" in the module (Commerce Stripe's) issue queue and file the bug against the "documentation".  Installation instructions that are wrong are a bug and need to be fixed by the maintainers.